# Probability Normal Disitrubution, $P(X \le 1.5)$

Tags: probability, statistics

I think this is simple but I'm not sure how it works (I probably just dozed off while reading this part).

The important info is that $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $3$ and standard deviation $1$.

I eventually end up with $P(\frac{X-3}{1}\le \frac{1.5-3}{1})$

When I looked in the book it says that this can be written simple as $P(Z \le -1.5)$ which naturally gives me $N(-1.5)$ or $1-N(1.5)$.

But I'm not understanding how to acquire $P(Z \le -1.5)$ from the $P(\frac{X-3}{1} \le \frac{1.5-3}{1})$.

Sorry if this seems a little dumb and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: They set $\frac{X-3}{1} = Z$. Where $Z$ has standard normal distribution.

Comment: $X-\mu$ shifts the mean to $0.$    Then division by $\sigma$ scales the standard deviation so that is  1.

Comment: $Z = \dfrac{X-3} 1$ and $\dfrac{1.5-3} 1 = -1.5.\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $X$ follows normal distribution, where $\mu=3$ and $\sigma=1$. Then $\Pr(X<x)=\Pr\left(\dfrac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not understanding how to acquire P(Z <= -1.5) from the P(X-3 / 1 <= 1.5-3 / 1).

We let $Z=(X-3)/1$ and since $(1.5-3)/1= -1.5$ therefore $(X-3)/1\leq (1.5-3)/1$ becomes $Z\leq -1.5$  .

---

And as Misakov added, the *reason* we choose this Z is that if $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ has a standard normal distribution, $Z\sim\mathcal N(0, 1^2)$ , and we can use this to look up standard normal tables (our Z-tables).